# Set SKSpriteNode position from a corner

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, xcode6

I'm making a game in SpriteKit and Swift and I want to align a random X positioned rectangles to a Y point. I have the code written but since the rectangles have different sizes and the position is set with the center of the rectangle, I can't choose a Y point that will align all the rectangles.

Here you can see the problem. I would like to align the bottom of all the rectangles.

[image]

What could I do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Either subtract half of the rectangle's height, or adjust the anchor point of the node.

Comment: How can I adjust the anchor point of the node?

Comment: It's a property on the node. It takes a CGPoint with values from 0.0 to 1.0, where 0.0, 0.0 is the bottom left corner of the node. Default is 0.5, 0.5.

Comment: Oh, I just figured out! Thanks for your help! :DDDD Sorry I can't mark your answer as correct...

Comment: No problem. In the future though, please include attempts you have already made at solving the problem in your questio.